# Sonatype Nexus Repository error: One or more objects could not be deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, nexus, nexus3

Ǐ am running my sonatype nexus repository on Docker container which is hosted on one Ec2 instance. It was working perfectly till yesterday.

Today i was trying to upload node artifact but it is was not uploading process was stuck for few mins and throws below error.

```
npm ERR! code E500
npm ERR! 500 Server Error - GET https://artifacts.testorg
.com/repository/dev-group/@types%2fnode
```

Also I am not able to login through any npmrc file to the nexus repo. I am using Sonatype Nexus Repository ManagerOSS 3.41.1-0.

I tried to upload the same artifact manually but it is throwing below error.

```
One or more objects could not be deleted (Service: null; Status Code: 200; Error Code: null; Request ID: 4Y0T479TA4PYfwdse0XD1; S3 Extended Request ID: U+1VSeJIlpAYF+fajEJ+N/7BIb3bzO4SYuFc+jD####5/NdH8RTI4iFq#####ENYtTW8=; Proxy: null)
```

I checked the docker container logs but it was also showing an issue with s3, I checked the credential provided to nexus which uploads to the bucket blob store it was working properly so i am assuming this is not issue with bucket or credential.

here's is the error which i found in docker container logs.

```
org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ViewServlet - Failure servicing: PUT /repository/dev-private/@test-package%2fcore
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.MultiObjectDeleteException: One or more objects could not be deleted
```